# How to generate interactive 'dialog' checklist from command output?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, dialog

I want to show a list of all `*.swp` files in `~/dir` (automatically checked).  How can I make the following work in a *shell script*?

```
options=$(find ~/dir -name '*.swp' | awk '{print v++,$1, "on"}')
cmd=(dialog --separate-output \
            --ok-label "Delete" \
            --checklist `"Select options:" 22 76 16)
choices=$("${cmd[@]}" "${options[@]}" 2>&1 >/dev/tty)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close.  This seems to be what you wanted to do:

```
#!/bin/bash
options=$(find ~/dir -name '*.swp' | awk '{print $1, "on"}')
cmd=(dialog --stdout --no-items \
        --separate-output \
        --ok-label "Delete" \
        --checklist "Select options:" 22 76 16)
choices=$("${cmd[@]}" ${options})
```

These changes were needed:

- use the `--stdout` option
- get rid of a stray backtic on the line with `--checklist`
- omit the "tag" number at the beginning of each record, and use `--no-items`

@agc pointed out that the `[@]` in `${options[@]}` is unnecessary (though it happened to work).

Comment: There's no need to write `${options[@]}`, since _$options_ isn't really an array, it's a string.  To verify that it's not an array, append `echo :${options[1]}:` -- it returns `::`.